# I am looking for how to draw a vertical line on a table component of material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a good way to do it?
I am looking for the way...
However, I can't reach reliable information.
https://material-ui.com/ja/components/tables/

Comment: do u want to add border on all sides of all cells in material ui table ?

Comment: absolutely yes.   I added  {{border : 1px}}  on style.. but it didn't work well.

Comment: Posted answer, give like if it works

Comment: did it not work ?

Comment: sorry i get back to you lately. im gonna check it. thanks

Comment: After hours of searching, I decided to add borders around cells, to make up verticle lines. I will add this as an answer. It works. It is a bit unconventional but does the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make a div above the material-ui table with a unique className, then in css make following changes

```
eg:
<div className="uniqueName">
   <Material UI Table/>  //material ui table here
</div>
in Css

.uniqueName th,
td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not conventional, but it does the trick. I achieved this by adding Borders around each `<TableCell>` component. You can also wrap `<TableRow>` or `<TableHead>` components. Given below is an example of how to add a `Right Border` on a cell. If you want the middle verticle line, then add a `Right Border` on all the `<TableCell>` of the first column.

```
const styles = theme => {
    tableRightBorder : { borderWidth: 0, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red',borderStyle: 'solid'} // or borderTop: '1px solid red'
}

...

class TableComponent ...

{ classes } = this.props; 

<Table >
    <TableHead>
        <TableRow >
            <TableCell className={classes.tableRightBorder}>Column 1</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Column 2</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
        <TableRow>
            <TableCell className={classes.tableRightBorder}>Cell 1</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Cell 2</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    </TableBody>
</Table>

export default withStyles(styles)(TableComponent)
```

This will look like this...

[image: **strong text**]

---

For a complete working component of the above image, try this table

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

import {
    Table,
    TableBody,
    TableCell,
    TableHead,
    TableRow,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {},
    tableRightBorder: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderRightWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
    },
}));

const DataTable = props => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Table>
            <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell className={classes.tableRightBorder}>
                        Column 1
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Column 2</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell className={classes.tableRightBorder}>
                        Cell 1
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Cell 2</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
    );
};

DataTable.propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string,
};

function mapStateToProps() {}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(DataTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to do it like this; wrap the component with styling and use it as a new component:

```
const CellWithRightBorder = withStyles((theme: Theme) => 
  createStyles({
    root: {
      borderRightWidth: 1,
      borderRightColor: theme.palette.grey[300],
      borderRightStyle: "solid",
    },
  })
)(TableCell);


const MyTable = () => {
  <TableContainer component={Paper}>
    <Table size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <CellWithRightBorder>Bla</CellWithRightBorder>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
    </Table>
  </TableContainer>
}
```